# Font management tools for Mac

Tags: fonts, mac, font-management

It's been a few years since I've visited this topic, one which has been one of Apples biggest issues since OS9.

Font management. I have been using Font Explorer however I've never been very impressed as it crashes a lot and my font database has corrupted a few times which is infuriating.

Can anyone suggest their favourites and why?

Thanks very much indeed.

Comment: Hi Alex! Currently, I feel your question is a little too broad. Could you go into more detail in your question about what you need from your font management tool? Asking for our favorites isn't a question type we like here at Stack Exchange. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using FontAgentPro from www.insidersoftware.com for over a decade. Good app.

I tried FontXplorer back when it was free, it was good, but I wasn't overly impressed at that time. I'm sure it's gotten better since I saw it last.

I've also tried Extensis Suitcase - That pile will NEVER touch any system I own again.

Of course, the Mac OS has FontBook built in. You could use that. Although it's nowhere near as feature rich as the others.

Just my 2¢.

Comment: I've been using FontXplorer since it was free also, and I'm pretty happy with the paid version.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm trialing the new 3.5 version of FX just because I know it but if it crashes me out or corrupts again I'm going to move to FAP (incidentally, I have vague recollections of using FAP after Adobe Type Manager was depricated, I think I liked it too but it was LONG ago)

Answer (score 1):

I just use RightFont from http://rightfontapp.com which is a lightweight font manager and super convenient. My team member also use it everyday.

Comment: This is the best. Also it can Sync your font's via Dropbox.

Comment: Looks like a great app… but they don’t seem to offer a trial version at all? Fork over $50 without the ability to try it out at all? Meh. :-/